# Change add to cart Button with product Enquiry Form In woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to change Add to cart Button in woocommerce, wordpress with Product Enquiry Form/Button. My Current wordpress version is 4.8.1 and woocommerce version is 3.1.2. Can somebody pls help me.

Comment: What do you want actually ? you want a enquiry form in product details page ?

Comment: Yes, I have a restaurant website where all products are added, when a customer clicks on the product it show add to cart, But instead of add to cart i want enquiry form. We dont sell anything online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To deactivate add to cart button place the following code to your theme's functions.php

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_purchasable', false );
```

Now coming to the part of showing enquiry form in product page, there are many free plugins to do that, so you don't have to write a single piece of code.

[Here](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-product-enquiry/) is one that I was using for that. This will add a enquiry form to your product details page.

Comment: Thank you soo much my add to cart button is removed, Is there a way where we replace Add to cart Button with Enquiry Form, Like when a customer clicks on the button immediately enquiry form should pop up.

Comment: Add to cart button being replaced to Enquiry Button

Comment: [WooCommerce Catalog Enquiry](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-catalog-enquiry/) is more suitable. Check out their [demo](http://wcmpdemos.com/addon/catalog_enquiry/product/flying-ninja/)

Comment: Thank you sooo much